# Automatically Reload Template Files

Tags: grails

I have a pretty standard 2.0.3 Grails app and I've executed `grails install-templates` which places files list.gsp, edit.gsp, etc. in src/templates/scaffolding/ directory.  These files are not automatically reloaded when a change is made to them.  Is there a way I can get these to be automatically reloaded so I don't have to stop/start the app every time I make a change?  I've tried looking at watchedResources but that seems to be plugin development related.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that the "watched-resources" mechanism only applies to plugins.  The correct fix for this would be to modify the core `ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy` to add

```
def watchedResources = "file:./src/templates/scaffolding/*"
```

and it's probably worth submitting a [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS) to that effect.  In the mean time, you may be able to get it working by writing a simple plugin of your own to "inject" this behaviour into the scaffolding plugin.  Do `grails create-plugin watch-scaffolding` and then use the following for the plugin descriptor:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPlugin

class WatchScaffoldingGrailsPlugin {
    def version = "0.1"
    def grailsVersion = "2.0 > *"
    def dependsOn = [:]
    def pluginExcludes = [ "grails-app/views/error.gsp" ]

    def title = "Watch Scaffolding Plugin"
    def author = "Your name"
    def authorEmail = ""
    def description = '''\
Watches for changes to scaffolding templates and reloads dynamically-scaffolded
controllers and views.
'''
    // URL to the plugin's documentation
    def documentation = "http://grails.org/plugin/watch-scaffolding"

    // watch for changes to scaffolding templates...
    def watchedResources = "file:./src/templates/scaffolding/*"

    // ... and kick the scaffolding plugin when they change
    def onChange = { event ->
        event.manager.getGrailsPlugin('scaffolding').notifyOfEvent(
            GrailsPlugin.EVENT_ON_CHANGE, null)
    }

    // rest of plugin options are no-op
    def onConfigChange = { event -> }
    def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml -> }
    def doWithSpring = { }
    def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx -> }
    def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext -> }
    def onShutdown = { event -> }
}
```

Now in your application's `BuildConfig.groovy` add

```
grails.plugin.location.'watch-scaffolding' = '../watch-scaffolding'
```

(or whatever is the appropriate relative path from the root of your app to the root of the plugin) and your scaffolding template changes should start to reload automatically.

(This is tested on Grails 2.1, I initially tried using [influences](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#participatingInAutoReloadEvents) but it didn't have any effect, however forcing an `onChange` event in the scaffolding plugin had the required result.)

Comment: This works great for .gsp files but doesn't seem to pick up the Controller.groovy file for some reason.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I see the same thing - changing `Controller.groovy` doesn't cause an `onChange` event.  The documentation suggests that there is special handling for `watchedResources` that are `.groovy` files: "If the watched resources specify a Groovy file, when it is changed it will automatically be reloaded and passed into the onChange closure in the event object", and I guess that since `Controller.groovy` isn't a Groovy file in the usual sense (it doesn't get compiled and reloaded) it isn't firing the event.

Comment: More interestingly though, changing a view template _after_ having changed `Controller.groovy` ought to cause the controller to be reloaded too (any change to a view triggers a full re-scaffold).  But it doesn't.  In this case my suspicion is that the scaffolded controller _is_ in fact being regenerated but because the regenerated class has the same name as the old one and Grails is attempting to compile it in the same classloader, the classloader gives us back the old `Class` object rather than a new one...

Answer (score 3):

This code flushes scaffolding cache. You can create a specific admin action for it:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.view.
  ScaffoldingViewResolver.scaffoldedViews.clear()
```

Comment: This is a good quick fix, but I was looking for something a little more automatic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [GRAILS-755](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-755), this has been fixed, but I don't think it has because they don't reload for me either.

From that Jira, here is a possible workaround:

> Use the console plugin, and run this command to clear the dynamic
>   scaffolded view cache:
>
> ​def scaffoldedView =
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.view.ScaffoldingViewResolver.scaffoldedViews.clear()​
>
> After that, the next time I request a page, it doesn't find it in the
>   cache, and thus goes back to the disk to recreate it.